# How to use Apache as proxy for browser?

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy

Is there a quick solution?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you got mod_proxy loaded and add below config:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
  ProxyRequests On
  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0
  </Proxy>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) as a forward proxy.